# How to run a command with the same name as a PowerShell alias?

Tags: powershell

I have a few command line utilities that have the same name as PowerShell aliases. For example `where` (alias for `Where-Object`) shadows the `where` tool that comes with Windows.

In bash I can skip aliases using `\` or `command` like `\where` or `command where`. Is there something similar in PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the extension when invoking:

```
& where.exe "arguments"
```

Or specify the full path.

See [About_Command_Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Thank you. That's a little inconvenient though. I have to remember the extension of the tool (`exe` or `bat`). Wish PS had a way to skip aliases for the command like bash.

Comment: To determine a file's extension or filepath run `& C:\Windows\System32\where.exe app_name`